# How to handle landing page with dynamic content for multiple clients - angular?

Tags: angular, dynamic

I have a landing page in web application with 32 clients and growing day to day. The landing page layout and 70% content remains same but each client have some specific text addition and changes. I am using angular ngIf to handle this. I want a better way to handle this before its too late. So far, I have JSON approach(loading HTML from JSON file based on client) in my mind. Is there a better way to handle this?

**Note: If possible without CMS.**

Answer (score 1):

I have used similar patterns with clients with similar needs before. I've found the best way is to do an API call to get the client data as soon as possible, and then use that data in perhaps the entry component to begin to render the correct html. Typically I've used some sort of loading overlay to hide the page until all of the client specific content is rendered.

In short, I've found the way you do it now to be effective even for large amounts of clients. Just make sure you aren't returning EVERY client in the API call to avoid a slow initial load for the page.